# Apache Spark with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I'm trying to connect MongoDB from Spark. Please help me to resolve the below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.$conforms()Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less;
```

Thanks

Comment: Fixed the previous error but got a new one
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ConnectionString

Comment: Can you please provide the code you are trying to execute and the error you are getting?

Comment: Solved that after changing the mongo-spark-connector_2.11 to mongo-spark-connector_2.10. Thanks anyway